# Antiderivative of $3\cos(x^3)\sin{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am practicing for an exam by randomly picking an expression to anti-differentiate when I came up with this one: $3\cos(x^3)\sin{x}$
. How would I go about tackling this? I tried using integration by parts:
$$\int3\cos(x^3)\sin{x}dx = 3\cos(x^3)(-\cos{x})-\int\sin(x)*-9x^2\sin(x^3) dx$$

This just ends up leaving the integral on the RHS even more complicated, in my opinion. I would appreciate it if somebody could show me how to solve this antiderivative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what makes you think that the function is integrable into elementary functions?  Not every function has a "nice" integration.

Comment: There are a lot of expressions that don't have a nice formula for their antiderivative; e.g. $e^{-x^2}$. If this is simply a random expression, then this might be one of them. Do you have any other reason to believe it does have an antiderivative in terms of common functions?

Comment: @robjohn I didn't think about that... in that case, what other types of functions would be necessary?

Comment: @DougM Even though I guess this type of integral is not going to be on my exam, I would still appreciate it if you could possibly guide me through the process.

Comment: @RayDansh: would be necessary for what? For your exam? I have no idea. That would depend on what was gone over in class.

Comment: @robjohn Oh I was wondering what functions would be necessary to solve the expression. I think you mentioned they weren't elementary?

Comment: @RayDansh: the function $\cos\left(x^3\right)\sin(x)$ is locally integrable, so an antiderivative exists. However, that anti-derivative may not be expressible in terms of any common functions. $\int e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be expressed in terms of the [erf function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), whose definition is $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$. In this case, the function is simply defined as the integral we are seeking, so it is sort of circular.

Comment: @robjohn Okay, thanks for the info. I looked at WolframAlpha, and it wasn't able to give me anything useful as well.

Comment: If you need functions to antidifferentiate which are guaranteed to have an elementary solution, get a friend to choose a function, differentiate it and give you the result.  Of course you have to trust your friend to do the differentiation correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bad idea to just randomly come up with integrals and attempt to integrate them. There are a lot of functions with no anti-derivative expressible in elementary functions. In particular, $e^{x^2}$ is an example. According to wolframalpha, this integral is also not expressible in terms of elementary functions.

A lot of the problems you see in your textbook and from class are chosen to be solvable using the techniques you used. So it would be a much better idea to do extra problems in your textbook rather than coming up with random integrals, as the textbook problems will have a solution, while your problem may not.